# Setting background color/image

Tags: java, awt

```
graphics.setColor(Color.blue);
graphics.fillRect(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight);
```

Instead of setting the background to the color blue, is there a way I can show an image from a specified file?

p.s Can the image be a GIF(and move?)

Answer (score 2):

What about drawImage method of Graphics class?

Here is an example
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html

"Image I/O has built-in support for GIF, PNG, JPEG, BMP, and WBMP". I think it can easily move too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about GIF but you can normally show other images.

In the constructor, load the image like this

```
backGroundImage = new ImageIcon("my-image.png").getImage();
```

Then render it every time with `Graphics`.

```
graphics.drawImage(backGroundImage, 0, 0, myWidth, myHeight);
```

Hope this helps.